# Swift closure with parameter syntax

Tags: swift, closures

I'm learning swift and I'm stuck on the crazy closure with parameters syntax. The following works as the "right way" to do it.

```
enum Brew: Int {
    case lager
    case barleyWine
    case porter
}

let beer = { (kind: Brew) -> Void in
    print( "\(kind), smooth!")
}

let gin = { () -> Void in
    print("gin & juice")
}

func sip( on drink: () -> Void ) {
    print("Sip...")
    drink()
}

func sip( on drink: (Brew) -> Void ) {
    print("Sip...")
    drink(brew.porter)
}

sip( on: beer )
sip( on: gin )
```

This prints...

```
Sip...
porter, smooth!
Sip...
gin & juice
```

However, that doesn't make much sense to me. The way it is coded any time I call sip() with a beer it assumes its a porter. It seems like I should be able to specify the brew in the call to sip rather than in the sip definition. Something like this...

```
sip( on: beer( brew.porter )
```

That way the beer closure is parameterized when it is called. Isn’t that more readable and useful? Why would it NOT be this way? Is there a syntax that accomplishes this?

Also, shouldn't there be a way to write one sip() method with variable parameters so that it can take beer OR gin? How?

Closures are confusing!

Comment: What do you want `sip` to do though? And what do you want the closure to do? Right now you're passing a closure that takes a parameter, and `sip` invokes it by passing a `.porter`. The example you provide of what you want doesn't make sense to me. It looks like you want to pass both the closure and the parameter into it; it's not clear why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, shouldn't there be a way to write one sip() method with variable parameters so that it can take beer OR gin?

Right now, `beer` and `gin` are different types of closures (`beer` takes a parameter while `gin` doesn't), which is why you need two overloads of `sip` - one to handle each type. Imagine what would happen if there were a single `sip` that could accept both of them. How would it know whether to pass a parameter or not?

On the other hand, if your ultimate goal is something like this:

```
sip(on: beer(brew.porter))
```

Then declaring a single `sip` *is* possible.

Right now, doing `beer(brew.porter)` will call the `beer` closure. The `beer` closure returns `Void`, and `Void` can't be passed into `sip`, so that won't work. Your intuition might say "Why can't `beer(brew.porter)` return another closure, that, when called with no parameters, drinks a beer with a porter brew?" And congrats, you have discovered [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

You can change `beer` to do exactly that:

```
let beer = { (kind: Brew) -> (() -> Void) in // a closure that returns a closure!
    // return { () -> Void in print("\(kind), smooth!") }
    return { print( "\(kind), smooth!") } // short-hand
}
```

And now you only need this `sip`:

```
func sip( on drink: () -> Void ) {
    print("Sip...")
    drink()
}
```

In the real world though, you often can't change `beer` (because it's someone else's code, or it doesn't make sense). In that case, you must change how you call `sip`:

```
// "{}" indicates a closure! You are putting the closure call "beer(brew.porter)" inside another closure.
sip(on: { beer(brew.porter) })
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasnt understanding the purpose of closures as basically verbs that can be passed to other verbs. Beer and gin are not verbs. They are "whats" not "hows". So my example was causing me to misunderstand the role of closures. I think I'm getting it now. Thanks again.